# How to randomly retrieve images from my mysql database?

Tags: php, image, random

Okay, so I've made one php file to output the images this is the sample code for the output page:

mysql_connect (" "," "," ") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db (" ") or die(mysql_error());

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store"); 
$number=mysql_num_rows($query); 

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM store ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $number");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))     
{       
    echo '<img src=get.php?id=$row["id"]>';
}
```

The get.php that the img tag is referring to has this code:

mysql_connect (" "," "," ") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db (" ") or die(mysql_error());

```
 $id = addslashes ($_REQUEST['id']);


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id= $id ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$content = $row['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
 echo $content;
```

All I'm getting are a series of torn page icons on the output page. I could have made a very simple mistake seeing as how I am still learning php. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store ORDER BY RAND()");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){       
    echo '<img src="get.php?id='.$row[id].'" />';
}
```

You can also `echo mysql_error();` to see if there are any errors in your mysql statements.

You should also use mysql_real_escape_string() instead of addslashes()

Or consider [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for an even more secure solution.

<strike>To debug, go to get.php?id=1. If you see an image get.php is working and the main file is not.</strike>

Have you made sure that get.php connects to the database as well as the main file?

Comment: when I put in get.php?id=1, it does show the image, but I still don't understand what I did wrong with the main file.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string nor addslashes will do no help here. although prepared statements will

Comment: thanks, could you tell me why those changes to the code worked?

Comment: Putting your quotes in the right places is very important (compare my img tag to yours). Wesley also mentioned that you didn't need to use LIMIT while selecting every row anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are some illogical things in this script.

1. You select EVERYTHING from store (* equals all fields). This is very, very expensive. If you want to use this you should use SELECT COUNT(id) FROM store.
2. You use the count, to LIMIT. But the limit will always be the same as the amount of rows. Which makes LIMIT irrelevant?
3. You should not use addslashes for escaping your values. Use mysql_real_escape_string instead. [Check it out here](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

I am not sure what values are in your database, perhaps you could post some? Perhaps you need to perform strip slashes, since you probably save values with slashes in your database?

Comment: there are six columns in the table: "id","name","image","com","desc",and "url". "id" is int type, "name" is varchar(50), "image" is BLOB type. "com", "desc", and "url" are all text type.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string will help no more than addslashes here

Comment: selecting every field is not that expensive. however, selecting all rows is.

Comment: I'd have to disagree on that, perhaps not in manners of performance on MySQL itself, but traffic-wise this can be a killer in high-traffic websites, or large processes/importing or updating scripts.

And yes, ofcourse I do also point at selecting all rows :). Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

> All I'm getting are a series of torn page icons on the output page.

In fact, you create kind of "denial of service" attack against your site, mking it run dozens PHP scripts and opening dozens sql connections per single page request. No wonder yor server being overloaded with such a flood and shows no pictures.

Also note that your code suffering from SQL injection.
Either change addslashes to `intval()` or add quotes around $id in the query (otherwise escaping will make no sense)

Comment: Could you explain SQL injection and "escaping" please? Does intval() cure SQL injection?

Comment: intval() has nothing to do with injections in general. there is no cure_all_injections_for_me() function. but in this particular case it will help