# Selecting random images using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing images path it is like this

```
id i_id img         date

1   0   im.png  2015-05-12
2   0   im1.png 2015-05-12
3   0   im2.png 2015-05-12
```

And i am trying to echo out images using an src tag in php but what i need to do is that i need to echo out images in random manner and the table will grow also how to do this?. is it a php part or mysql part?.

Comment: I'd use `ORDER BY RAND()` in MySQL

Comment: There are a ton of questions on this already.

Comment: @JayBlanchard is it like this SELECT *img_table ORDER BY RAND(id);

Comment: OK, so what is the issue?

Comment: Google "show random image php mysql" many results. This http://stackoverflow.com/a/5660466/ being a good bet. Wouldn't you say so *Sam?* - @JayBlanchard It's `mysql_` but the idea/concept is there. They just need to use the other APIs ;-)

Comment: *I like it Ralph.* Older, yet still relevant @Fred-ii- CAD?

Comment: *si signore Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options. You can either do an ORDER BY RAND(), or you can do a select all and randomize the selected rows in PHP.

Option 1:

```
SELECT * from IMAGES ORDER BY RAND();
```

Option 2:

```
//select images (example uses mysql_ library; it's deprecated so DON'T USE IT!)
$query = "SELECT * FROM IMAGES";
$result = mysql_query($connection, $query)
$rows = mysql_fetch_all($result);
//randomize the array of images
shuffle($rows);
//output the images here
```

Option 1 can get very slow with large datasets. In my experience, Option 2 is faster, but it would be worth doing your own tests to see what works best for you. Usually the difference will be only fractions of a second. Check the answers here for more information: [MySQL: Alternatives to ORDER BY RAND()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand) or here: [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

A third option is to generate random ids and select the albums that match those ids. This is only suitable if you don't have gaps in your ids. I have never tried this.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's just example code to illustrate the technique. Obviously it is better to use prepared statements anywhere where plain queries are being used, and to never use the mysql_ functions. I will edit my answer to make that clear.